# Why Mx is spoken as mɪks instead of mks?

Tags: pronunciation

In the dictionary -- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mx

> Mx in British English (mɪks IPA Pronunciation Guide IPA Pronunciation
> Guide , məks IPA Pronunciation Guide ) noun a title used by some
> people before a surname to avoid specifying a particular gender

Why Mx is spoken as `mɪks` instead of `mks`?

Comment: Are you asking why the inventor of that word decided to pronounce it /mɪks/? If so, that's not a question about learning English, and is unlikely to be unanswerable by citation. If not, please [edit] your question to say what you really want to know?

Comment: /mk/ is not a consonant blend used in English, so some short vowel is inserted, a schaw or /ɪ/  The /ɪ/  is an analogue of Mister or Mistress.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about learning English, and is unlikely to be answerable.

Comment: Possibly by analogy with "Ms" as well as for reasons stated.

Comment: But out of interest how exactly do you propose to pronounce /mks/? What English word would it resemble? How many syllables? Is the /m/ syllabic like "mmmkay"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term Mx can be pronounced in  *two* different ways, depending on one's dialect and region: /mɪks/ or /məks/

The sound of the letter M (not its pronunciation in the alphabet) is usually connected to the vowel that immediately follows. I can think of no instance where the **initial letter M** is followed by a **consonant sound**. Even a word such as **Mrs** is not an exception because it is pronounced *misiz* by native speakers since the honorific is a 15th century abbreviation of ***mistress***.

On the hand, the pronunciation of the letter X begins with a vowel sound,  [/ˈɛks/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/x) (ex). When the [prefix “ex-”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex-#Pronunciation) follows a stressed vowel it sounds like /gz/ e.g. /ɪgˈzɔːst/ (exhaust)  and /ɪgˈzæm/ (exam). When it  is followed by an unstressed vowel, it sounds like /ɪk/ as in /ˈeksaɪl/ (exile) and /'ekstrə/ (extra). Thus, some speakers pronounce Mx with the main stress on the first letter /m/ and others add the stress on the *ex* (x).